# Vue JS data binding not working for img src

Tags: data-binding, vuejs2, src

I am using vue 2 and vue-cli 3.  I am trying to bind the *src* of an  tag to a variable in data.

Specifically I am doing the following:

```
<img class="img-time-matters" :src="`./../assets/time-comparison-${locale}.png`">

export default {
   name: "home",
   components: {},  
   data() {
       return {
           locale: locale // 'en'
       };
   }
}
```

The binding works

Using Chrome developer tools and examining the network activity I see that the binding works:

http://localhost:8080/assets/time-comparison-en.png

However the resource is not found.

If I remove data binding at hard code the course path to:

```
<img class="img-time-matters" :src="`./../assets/time-comparison-en.png`">
```

Vue resolves the resource link to look for the image at:

http://localhost:8080/img/time-comparison-en.74a6f0ca.png

How do I get the Vue to data bind in such a way that it resolves the binding correctly (i.e. time-comparison-en.74a6f0ca.png).

Thanks!

Comment: Which webpack plugins/loaders are you using?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please try `require`

```
<img class="img-time-matters" :src="require(`../assets/time-comparison-${locale}.png`)">
```

Comment: Thanks ittus, much appreciated.  I spent a bit of time banging my head against this problem.

I saw this solution elsewhere but could not get it to work.  I misapplies the require function by using it as follows:

<img class="img-time-matters" :src=require("`../assets/time-comparison-${locale}.png`")>

I kept receiving a syntax error. The require function needs to go INSIDE the ". 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative solution to fix the issue, is to import the image first as a module before binding to src, here is an example

```
<script>
import logo from "../assets/logo_800_white_background.png";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imgPath: logo,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-6 max-w-[1155px] mx-auto">
    <div>
      <img
        :src="imgPath"
        alt="logo"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/about">about</router-link>
      <router-link to="/software">software</router-link>
      <router-link to="/hardware">hardware</router-link>
      <router-link to="/contact">contact</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```