# VueJS: Binding image file location data to the src property of img tag is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

First of all: I am aware of a similar question ([Vue JS data binding not working for img src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152795/vue-js-data-binding-not-working-for-img-src)) but I am still posting this question here since the solution of that question did not solve my problem.

I want to display an image in my web application (coded in VueJS), but unfortunately when I bind the image file location string to the `src` property of the `img` tag, the image is not shown in the web app.

I have the following code:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img src="@/assets/Home.jpg" />
    <img :src="src" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      src: "@/assets/Home.jpg",
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

The first img component gets displayed normally, but the second (which binds data to the src property) not.

I already tried (as suggested in [Vue JS data binding not working for img src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152795/vue-js-data-binding-not-working-for-img-src)):

```
<img :src="require(src)" />
```

which gave me the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/Home.jpg'"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665555/vue-require-dynamic-image/68665769#68665769). All you need to do is create a computed property that resolves the full path and requires the asset correctly.

Comment: Cool, up vote the answer in that thread if you found it useful so that it may help others in future.